# iCheck not working in dynamic checkbox

Tags: jquery, icheck

I am using this [iCheck plugin](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) to customize checkbox and radio.I have problem. I am loading the checkbox dynamically but the iCheck plugin is not working. If i load dynamically the checkbox.

This is how i load my  checkboxes.

```
 $('#myconatainer').load('getMycheckboxes.php');
```

and this is how I build the checkboxes

//getMycheckboxes.php

```
  foreach($list as $itm){
    $mydata .=  '<div class="media">'.
                   '<div class="media-left">'.
                       '<a href="#"><img src="..." ></a>'.
                   '</div>'.
             '<div class="media-body">'.
              '<h4 class="media-heading">Heading</h4>'.
              '<p><input type="checkbox" class="mycheck"></p>'.
             '</div>'.
            '</div>';
   }

   echo $mydata;
```

and in getMycheckboxes.php I build all the checkboxes. but when it is loaded the chekbox is not styled by icheck or the icheck plugin is not working.
how can I make this work to use icheck if I load my checkboxes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinitialize icheck plugin after adding checkboxes dynamically.